# Eclipse RCP plugin deployment and install in RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have a third-party Eclipse RCP application. I need to create a plugin with is start, when the application is started, or less before. My idea was, to create a plugin, extend the elipse.ui.startup Extension. In a separated class I implement the earlyStartup() method.

For testing I print only a line to the console. As far as the plan. If I export the plugin (Deployable plugin) and copy the jar to the RCP applications plugin directory, the plugin will not load. I can't see the plugins ID in the About / Installation Details

So I tried to start the RCP with the command -clean -debug -consolelog. The hope was to recreate the plugin cache.
The output is:

```
Install location:
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/
Configuration file:
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.700.v20200207-2156.jar
        eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/plugins/
    file:/c:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.700.v20200207-2156.jar
Splash location:
    c:\Tools\dev\Eclipse_RCP\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\com.acdp.product.tools.viewer.rcp\splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/C:/Tools/dev/Eclipse_RCP/.options loaded
Time to load bundles: 114
Starting application: 5947
setting instance location...
buffering System.out/err
Application started in : 8524ms
```

There is also a reference to the .options file. The content is:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/reconciler=true
```

Nothing specially for me.

Does anyone have an idea how I can create a plugin witch is starting while the eclipse startup? I guess I overlooking any important here. Perhaps it is also the wrong approach that I am following here.

Regards Bjoern

Additional what I actually have is:
Steps I do
File \ New \ Plugin-Project
-> template "Hello world Command"
File \ Export \ Deployable plugins
And this should install in the RCP

Comment: _"copy the jar to the RCP applications plugin directory"_ - I guess you mean the `plugins` folder, but this is not the right way to do it. If there is a `dropins` folder, you have to put the JAR there. Otherwise you have to install it. If it is not early enough via the _startup_ extension point, you can set the start level of a bundle in OSGi (in Eclipse, this can done via the p2 touchpoint action `setStartLevel`).

Comment: Very old versions of Eclipse would pick up new plug-ins in the plugins directory, but this hasn't worked since the "p2" update system was introduced (a long time ago now). Does the RCP actually include the p2 plugins?

Comment: Hi, 
simple copy to the plugin directory will not work. The RCP based on Eclipse 4.x. I tried to use the install new Software \ Add \ Archive \ the exported jar file. There I get the error message "No software site found at jar:file/c:/...../pluginTest_1.0.0.jar". I found actually no way to install the plugin.

Comment: The Archive has to be a "update site" (also known as a repository). See [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#exercise-create-an-update-site-your-plug-in)